# Solve the following equation: $\sqrt{4x^2 - 15x + 20} = 4x - 10 + 7\sqrt{x - 1}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> Solve the following equation. $$\large \sqrt{4x^2 - 15x + 20} = 4x - 10 + 7\sqrt{x - 1}$$

I try to let $2x - 6 = a$ and $\sqrt{x - 1} = b$. Then the equation becomes:

$$\sqrt{a^2 + 9b^2 - 7} = 2a + 7b + 2$$

with which I think about how stupid I am about what I am working.

> **Notation**: I am trying to do a solution involving inequalities. So I will be grateful if anyone can do that.

Comment: First find out for what values $x$ is defined, i.e. the argument of the squares needs to be non-negative.

Comment: More explicitely, you'll see that $x$ is at lezst 2,8... (if I computed correctly). This makes both right and left hznd positive. Square both sides, to get rid of the ledt hand square root. Push all terms to the left, except the remaining square roots. Then check again for poisitivity and square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $y = \sqrt{x-1}$, your equation is equivalent to
$$\sqrt{4(y^2+1)^2-15(y^2+1)+20} = 4(y^2+1)-10 + 7y$$

i.e.
$$\sqrt{4y^4 - 7y^2 + 9} = 4y^2 + 7y - 6$$

so squaring it, you get
$$4y^4 - 7y^2 + 9 = 16y^4 + 56y^3 + y^2 - 84y + 36$$

i.e.
$$12y^4 + 56y^3 + 8y^2 - 84y + 27 = 0$$

i.e.
$$(2y^2+2y-3)(6x^2+22x-9)=0$$

You get that
$$y= \frac{1}{6} \left(- 11 - 5 \sqrt{7} \right) \quad \text{or} \quad y= \frac{1}{2} \left(- 1 - \sqrt{7} \right) \quad$$ $$\text{or} \quad y= \frac{1}{2} \left(- 1 + \sqrt{7} \right) \quad \text{or} \quad y= \frac{1}{6} \left(- 11 + 5 \sqrt{7} \right) \quad $$

The first two ones are impossible because $y$ has to be positive, and the last one is impossible (because $4y^2+7y-6$ has to be positive) so you get 
$$\quad y= \frac{1}{2} \left(- 1 + \sqrt{7} \right)$$

i.e. $$x= \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(- 1 + \sqrt{7} \right)\right)^2+1 \quad \text{i.e. } \quad x= 3 - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{7}$$

Comment: When $y=\frac{1}{6}(-11+5\sqrt{7})$, $4y^2+7y-6$ is negative.  This should be rejected also.

Comment: You are right, thanks ! I edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t= \sqrt{x-1}\geq 0$ then we get $$\sqrt{4t^4 - 7t^2 + 9} = 4t^2+7t-6$$

and now square it, we get $$12t^4+56t^3+8t^2-84t+27=0$$

Now use divide this by $t^2$ (clearly $t \ne 0$) and we get $$3(4t^2+{9\over t^2}) -28(2t-{3\over t})+8=0$$

Let $y=2t-{3\over t}$ and we get $$3(y^2+12)-28y+8=0$$ so $$3y^2-28y+44=0$$

now solve this and then finish...

Answer (score 1):

The domain gives $x\geq1$.

Thus, for all root of the equation we obtain:
$$4x-10+7\sqrt{x-1}=\sqrt{4x^2-15x+20}=\sqrt{x^2+3x^2-15x+20}>x,$$ which gives
$$3x+7\sqrt{x-1}>10.$$

But for $x=1.5$ we see that
$$3x+7\sqrt{x-1}=4.5+\frac{7}{\sqrt2}<10$$ and since $3x+7\sqrt{x-1}$ increases, we obtain $x>1.5.$

In another hand, for $x>1.5$ we obtain:
$$4x-10+7\sqrt{x-1}=\sqrt{4x^2-15x+20}<2x,$$ which gives
$$2x+7\sqrt{x-1}<10.$$

Now, for $x=2$ we see that
$$2x+7\sqrt{x-1}=4+7>10$$ and since $2x+7\sqrt{x-1}$ increases, we obtain $x<2$.

Now, rewrite our equation in the following form:
$$\sqrt{4x^2-15x+20}-3\sqrt{x-1}=2(2x-5+2\sqrt{x-1})$$ or
$$\frac{4x^2-24x+29}{\sqrt{4x^2-15x+20}+3\sqrt{x-1}}=\frac{2(4x^2-24x+29)}{2x-5-2\sqrt{x-1}},$$ which gives $$4x^2-24x+29=0$$ and since $1.5<x<2,$ we obtain $$x=3-\frac{\sqrt7}{2}$$ or
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{4x^2-15x+20}+3\sqrt{x-1}}=\frac{2}{2x-5-2\sqrt{x-1}},$$ which gives
$$2\sqrt{4x^2-15x+20}+8\sqrt{x-1}=2x-5,$$ which is impossible because
$$2\sqrt{4x^2-15x+20}+8\sqrt{x-1}>2x>2x-5.$$
Id est, we got the following answer:
$$\left\{3-\frac{\sqrt7}{2}\right\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Squaring one times we get
$$-12x^2+16x-31=14(4x-10)\sqrt{x-7}$$
Squaring again and simplifying and factorizing we get
$$(36x^2-664x+709)(4x^2-24x+29)=0$$

Comment: Is $331$ a typo for $31$?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, thank you for your hint!